# Why we extend action class in struts 1.3

Tags: struts1

I'm currently learning Struts 1.3!

Why do we extend **Action** class in struts 1.3

```
public class LoginAction extends Action
```

And when i look into web.xml file the mapping says

```
<servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet</servlet-class>
```

what is the Significance of ActionServlet class, why ActionServlet is mapped with Action.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Simple answers:

1. Because that's how Struts 1 works.
2. Because you have to map requests to actions *somehow*.

Longer answers:

**1.** In S1 everything depends on subclassing framework classes.<sup>(See notes)</sup> The base `Action` class really only provides a small portion of framework functionality (messaging and resources, primarily), along with a small collection of other non-POJO framework classes, notably `ActionForm`.

In Struts (and in lots of older software) programs were written to implementations, not interfaces. `Action` is a class, not an interface. Most of the S1 framework's implementation references `Action`, meaning that in order to fulfill framework method signatures and return values, you *must* subclass `Action`.

**2.** One goal of MVC is to route requests to appropriate handlers. In S1 this is handled by the `ActionServlet`. It looks at the request and, based on the Struts configuration, determines which action will handle the request. It acts (more or less) as the controller.

---

For further study: A significant portion of functionality, and a main point of extension, lies further beneath the surface, in [the `RequestProcessor` class](http://struts.apache.org/release/1.3.x/apidocs/org/apache/struts/action/RequestProcessor.html). Note that instantiating actions to handle requests requires an `Action` to be returned. This means that requests must be handled by an `Action`, although any `Action` subclass may be used, e.g., your own actions, a framework action like `DispatchAction` or `ForwardAction`, etc.

I would add that your questions can be answered by reading the wealth of information available about Struts 1 on its site and on the internet. Since the source is available it's also important to check and verify assumptions against it. I might recommend looking at Struts 1.2 source instead of 1.3 since there's a small layer of functionality added that clouds the basics.

All this said, unless you have a very compelling reason to do so, studying Struts 1 is a waste of time. It's been EOL'd, hasn't been recommended for new projects for *years*, is written in a pretty old style, etc. Modern Java web frameworks are much, *much* easier to work with. Struts 1 was written a Pretty Long Time Ago, before inheritance had fallen out of favor, before annotations existed, before marker interfaces were used all over the place, etc.

Comment: Thank you so much for you efforts! But for me learning on the Java related things (technology/framework) would help me to explore the implementations of Java technology.

Comment: @JayJain And I'm saying study something that uses current best practices instead of something that forces you to write rigid, inflexible code.

Comment: Actually I have to work on existing applications which are all in Struts 1.3.